# SwiftUI XCUIElement - How to grab XCUIElement on the screen?

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, xcuielement

[TAKE_A_LOOK_AT_SCREENSHOT_HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3qRJ.png)

I'm facing an issue with the UI test written in SwiftUI.
I need to grab an element on the screen which is implemented with following the code:

```
HStack {
    Button(action: {
       if value != 0 {
          value -= 1
       }
    }) {
       Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
    }
    Text(String(value))
       .accessibilityIdentifier("person_\(text.lowercased())_count")
    Button(action: {
       value += 1
    }) {
       Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
    }
 }
```

When I'm trying to get access to minus.circle or plus.circle the recorder prints me the following code e.g for minus:

```
app.windows.children(matching: .other)
    .element.children(matching: .other)
    .element.children(matching: .other)
    .element.children(matching: .other)
    .element.children(matching: .other)
    .element.children(matching: .other)
    .element.children(matching: .other)
    .element.children(matching: .other)
    .element.children(matching: .button)
    .matching(identifier: "Remove").element(boundBy: 0)
```

**My question is**:

How to reduce the amount of calling `.children(matching: .other)` or create another correct path to get access to these buttons?

I tried to use:

```
var minusCircleTeens: XCUIElement { 
    app.windows.children(matching:.other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .other)
        .element.children(matching: .button)
        .matching(identifier: "Remove").element(boundBy: 0)
}

func removeTeens() {      
     minusCircleTeens.tap() 
}
```

And it works properly but I would like to cut the long path to the element and do that in a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use accessibility identifier to name your views

Comment: Yes, and it's available as a `View Modifier` on all SwiftUI elements. See the docs here for `Image`'s `accessibilityIdentifier`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/accessibilityidentifier(_:)/. As the docs note, this is for testing, not actual user accessibility usage.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your identifiers are unique, you can go with something like

```
func removeTeens() {      
     app.buttons["Remove"].tap()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command during the debug: `po XCUIApplication()` This will print all UI elements that you can use. I believe you can tap on the button image like this: `app.images["plus.circle"].tap()`. Unless you have more buttons like this, then add and use the accessibility identifier.